# Split String with Multiple Dates

Tags: python, regex, date, split

I am trying to create a function that splits a string on one or multiple dates

```
{0: 'Stabilizing (P1 events)(11/5/19) -3.8.4\xa0released',
 1: '(9/20/19)\-3.8.3 released; Enabled 100% for \xa0(released the APK to the store, not the actual app itself)',
 2: '(11/12/19) Accepted & Released. Enabled 100% for.',
 3: '(6/11/19) app released with feature flag disabled(9/11/19)\100% on  for P1 events',
 4: '(6/11/19) app released with feature flag disabled(9/11/19)\100% on for P1 events',
 5: '(1/6/20)\xa0Released with feature flag disabled & LiveChannel bug fixed.\xa0(Live Channels disabled)(2/13/20)\xa0FireTv\xa0100% on for P1 events'}
```

For example, string #3 in the example above would be split into:

`['(6/11/19)', 'app released with feature flag disabled', '(9/11/19)', '100% on  for P1 events']`

I have created another function that extracts the dates from each string

```
def extract_comments_date(date):
    val  = re.findall('(\d+/\d+/\d+)', date)
    if len(val) == 1:
        return f"({val[0]})"
    else:
        return [f"({i})" for i in val]
extract_comments_date(mydict[3])
output: ['(6/11/19)', '(9/11/19)']
```

But now I'm wondering how I can split a string on multiple delimiters (dates) that are stored in a list.

Comment: Try splitting on: `\(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}\)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough example or food for thought (sorry, eyelids closing!)...

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = re.compile(r'(\(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\))')

d = {0: 'Stabilizing (P1 events)(11/5/19) -3.8.4\xa0released',
 1: '(9/20/19)\-3.8.3 released; Enabled 100% for \xa0(released the APK to the store, not the actual app itself)',
 2: '(11/12/19) Accepted & Released. Enabled 100% for.',
 3: '(6/11/19) app released with feature flag disabled(9/11/19)\100% on  for P1 events',
 4: '(6/11/19) app released with feature flag disabled(9/11/19)\100% on for P1 events',
 5: '(1/6/20)\xa0Released with feature flag disabled & LiveChannel bug fixed.\xa0(Live Channels disabled)(2/13/20)\xa0FireTv\xa0100% on for P1 events'}

for key, value in d.items():
    splitting = pattern.sub(r'|\1|', value).split('|')
    splitting = [i for i in splitting if i] 
    print(splitting)
```

Output:

```
['Stabilizing (P1 events)', '(11/5/19)', ' -3.8.4\xa0released']
['(9/20/19)', '\\-3.8.3 released; Enabled 100% for \xa0(released the APK to the store, not the actual app itself)']
['(11/12/19)', ' Accepted & Released. Enabled 100% for.']
['(6/11/19)', ' app released with feature flag disabled', '(9/11/19)', '@% on  for P1 events']
['(6/11/19)', ' app released with feature flag disabled', '(9/11/19)', '@% on for P1 events']
['(1/6/20)', '\xa0Released with feature flag disabled & LiveChannel bug fixed.\xa0(Live Channels disabled)', '(2/13/20)', '\xa0FireTv\xa0100% on for P1 events']
```

Update: Since there are commas in the strings maybe split on | instead?  Some character not in the strings anyway.